# How to schedule tasks using Quartz.Net inside a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, quartz.net

I have created a windows service project in VS and in it I configure Quartz.Net to run a task immediately. The code that registers the task runs with no exception, but the task is never executed as far as my debugging can tell.

I can't be sure because debugging a Windows Service is very different. The way I do it is to programatically launching the debugger from my code. Quartz.Net runs jobs on a separate threads, but I'm not sure if VS2010 can see other running threads when debugging a Windows Service.

Has anyone done what I'm trying before? Any tips are appreciated.

PS. I don't want to use Quartz.Net's own Service.

Comment: Here is the step by step guide to implement the same: http://blog.nitinsawant.com/2014/10/draft-how-to-create-cron-job-windows.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most common reasons a job doesn't execute, is because you need to call the Start() method on the scheduler instance.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/faq.html#whytriggerisntfiring

But it's hard to say what the problem is if we don't have some sort of snippet of the code that does the scheduler creation and job registration.

Answer (score 5):

I see that this is a bit dated, but it came up many times in various searches!

Definitely check out this article, which uses an XML config when the scheduler is instantiated.
http://miscellaneousrecipesfordotnet.blogspot.com/2012/09/quick-sample-to-schedule-tasks-using.html

In case you would rather not use XML (dynamically created tasks and such), replace the "Run" procedure from the article above with something like this:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        // construct a scheduler factory
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TaskOne>()
                .WithIdentity("TaskOne", "TaskOneGroup")
                .Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("TaskOne", "TaskOneGroup")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(20).RepeatForever())
        .Build();
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        _scheduler.TriggerJob(job.Key);

        _scheduler.Start();
    }
```

**Note** - Using Quartz .NET 2.1.2, .NET 4

Cheers!

Comment: the url http://miscellaneousrecipesfordotnet.blogspot.com/2012/09/quick-sample-to-schedule-tasks-using.html does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used Quart.NET before in a Windows service. When the service starts-up I create the Scheduler Factory and then get the Scheduler. I then start the scheduler which implicitly reads in the configuration XML I have specified in the App.config of the service.

Quartz.NET basic setup: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html

App.config Setup Question: http://groups.google.com/group/quartznet/browse_thread/thread/abbfbc1b65e20d63/b1c55cf5dabd3acd?lnk=gst&q=%3Cquartz%3E#b1c55cf5dabd3acd